# Bit wise operators not working properly in java

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I tried running the below program but its not working properly.
Please help me.

```
package javaapplication2;
public class Fun {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int var1 = 3;
    int var2 = 2;
    int var3 = var1 & var2;
    System.out.println(var3);
   }
}
```

I got this error when i tried running in NetBeans:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Uncompilable source code - bad operand types for binary operator '&'
>     first type:  int
>     second type: boolean
>       at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:25)
>     Java Result: 1

Comment: You are not using any bitwise operators in that code.

Comment: @KevinEsche Compiled with error.

Comment: “Not working properly” is not a valid question.  State the behavior you expected, the behavior you are seeing, and include all error messages in full.

Comment: @Jesper Sorry. I have updated the code now..

Comment: Ok, so now it compiles. Why do you think `2` is the wrong answer?

Comment: Not working properly?. Is working as spected

Comment: That code does not produce that message. Both operands are clearly `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code could look like this instead:

```
package javaapplication2;
public class Fun {
    private static final int A = 0x3; //3
    private static final int B = 0x2; //2   
    public static void main(final String[] argv) {
        System.out.print(A & B);

    }
}
```